# The file does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on my project last night, I saved it as usual and closed down eclipse. I woke up today to continue with it as it's in for next week and this happens :

[image]

I have no idea what to do. Is there any possibility I can get my classes back?

thanks =/

Comment: First of all, please don't link to off-site images. Second, can you check your `workspace` folder in your Windows home folder for the classes?

Comment: @devnull It is, I just edited it in.

Comment: had never encountered such problem yet... but i would definitely look at the workspace folder to confirm what has gone wrong .... i don't think there is any other way .... !!!!

Comment: Hint for the future: backup, version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the project is inside the eclipse workspace folder
2. Delete the project from eclipse (**DON'T SELECT "DELETE PROJECT CONTENTS ON DISK"**)
3. Restart eclipse
4. Import the project

Answer (score 1):

Restarted Eclipse ? Seems like it crashed. Maybe you copy the folder of the project and import it as a new project.

Comment: I've closed and reopened it and the same thing happens.

Comment: @hoedding will suggest you to restart your machine